# Embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ respects $\leq$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

I have to verify that the embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ respects $\leq$. That is, verify for $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$ that if $a\leq b$ as rationals, then $a\leq b$ as real numbers.

I have this idea. We can embed $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ by associating them with the Dedekind cuts $(-\infty,a]|(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]|(b,\infty)$.

$a\leq b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ $\Leftrightarrow (-\infty,a]\subseteq (-\infty,b] \Leftrightarrow \in \mathbb{Q}$

Which holds.

Comment: If you want to prove something so obviously true that you don't even know where to begin, then the place to begin is always with the definitions (that's also the place to begin in many other cases, just as a general tip). What is your definition of $\leq$ on the rationals? What is your definition of $\leq$ on the reals? What is your definition of the embedding of $\Bbb Q$ into $\Bbb R$?

Comment: (Actually, this question is so basic and dependent on what specifically _your_ definitions are (there are mny options for each) that if we don't know them, we can't really help you write a proof.)

Comment: Well. How do you define the real numbers, and what is the embedding that comes out of this definition?

Comment: The embeding is defined using Dedekind cuts. We embed Q in R by associating $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}^{\geq}$ with the dedekind cut $[0,\frac{p}{q})|[\frac{p}{q},\infty)$

Answer (score 2):

First of all lets be precise. If you define $\mathbb{R}$ as Dedekind cuts of $\mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathbb{Q}$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}$ via $q\mapsto\big((-\infty, q), [q,\infty)\big)$. The total ordering on the Dedekind cuts is defined by the inclusion on the left component, i.e $(A,B)\leq (A', B')$ iff $A\subseteq A'$.

So let $p, q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $p\leq q$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then obviously $(-\infty,p)\subseteq(-\infty, q)$ and thus $p\leq q$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is easier with Cauchy sequences. If $a \leq b$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, then the constant Cauchy sequences $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ satisfy $a_n \leq b_n$ for big n (actually, for all $n$), so $a \leq b$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi its not a matter od being easier or not. Read the question. His definition of reals is Dedekind cuts.

Comment: ah, ok. I did not see the edit (the original question did not specify  what definition of real numbers the OP was using).

Comment: by the way: it is not so important, but since your claim about the circularity of my answer was groundless, maybe you should consider removing the downvote.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi update the answer with proper explanation and i will.

Comment: answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** (October 25, 2017). *This is an updated version, according to the comments below, of an answer using Cauchy sequences, and written before the OP's editing of the question*.

We can define the set $\mathbb{Q}^+$ of non-negative rational numbers as $0$ and all the rational numbers whose numerator and denominator have the same sign. Then the definition of $a \leq b$ as rationals can be given by saying there exists $x \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $b = a+x$ (it is an easy exercise to check that this is equivalent to the standard definition $u/v \leq w/z$ if $uz  \leq vw$).

Now identify $x$ with the corresponding real number via the natural embedding $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that associates to $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ the (constant) Cauchy sequence $\{x\}$. This sequence is eventually non negative, hence $0 \leq x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and so $a \leq a+x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

But this precisely means that $a \leq b$ as real numbers, and you are done.

Comment: "The definition of $a \leq b$ as rationals is that there exists $x \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $b = a+x$." 1) If that is not the OP's definition, then this answer is unlikely to help. 2) This just shifts the burden of definition: what is $\Bbb Q^+$? (Yes, I am aware that for the sake of sanity, we must stop defining things at some point, but I would personally prefer if that point was $\leq$ on the integers or naturals, rather than just a special subset of the rationals.)

Comment: (1) Well, if this is not the definition, I guess it will be one equivalent to this. Probably it can be a useful exercise to check the equivalence of the two definitions, if they are different. (2) $\mathbb{Q}^+$=non-negative rational numbers.

Comment: (2) And how do you tell that a rational number is non-negative?

Comment: Come on, I have no crystal ball to guess what is the OP's starting level. This is a possible answer, he/she can also sit down and try to fill up the details, if necessary.

Comment: I know, but there is one point I want to drive home here: If you define $\leq$ on the rationals in terms of $\Bbb Q^+$, then my (and most peoples', I would presume) standard definition of $\Bbb Q^+$ (the set of rationals $x$ with $0\leq x$) would make the definitions circular. That's something I want to be certain that we avoid here, and that is why I'm pestering you.

Comment: -1: The definition is circular and thus invalid. The proper definition is given in wiki (based on the ordering of integers): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Ordering

Comment: There is no circularity. The non-negative rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}^+$ can be defined as $0$ and the rational numbers whose numerator and denominator have the same sign.

Comment: Once you have this, you define $a \leq b$ as $b = a+x$, where $x \in \mathbb{Q}^+$. Where is the circularity?

Comment: Yes, it is true that with this definition you have avoided circularity, and unltimately defined the ordering of the rationals in terms of the ordering of the integers / naturals. You did it in a rather roundabout and non-standard way, in my opinion, but that's not as important.

Comment: Roundabout and problematic. @FrancescoPolizzi how would that work for reals then? What is a non-negative real number?

Comment: @freakish A non-negative real number is the limit of a Cauchy sequence of non-negative rational numbers. Where is the problem?

Comment: My definition can be roundabout, but it is clearly equivalent to the standard one (simple computation).  So it *cannot* be problematic, unless the standard one is.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following definitions for order:

for $\mathbb{Q}$: $\frac{a}{b}\leq\frac{c}{d}$ if and only if $ad\leq bc$

for $\mathbb{R}$: $a\leq b$ if and only if $\exists c(a+c^2=b)$

as far as I know these are these are fairly standard definitions relying on only multiplication, addition and ordering of integers.

But as has been said it, the definitions that you use will shape your answer.

Comment: The definition for $\mathbb{Q}$ is incomplete: you need to assume that $b,d> 0$. As for $\mathbb{R}$: how would you prove that this is a well defined ordering? Namely transitivity? Note that existence of square roots actually follows from completness of $\leq$. This is a horrible definition to work with. There are many standard ways to define ordering on $\mathbb{R}$, depending on the definition of $\mathbb{R}$. If $\mathbb{R}$ is defined axiomatically then its simply an axiom. On the other hand if you defined it via Cauchy sequences of rationals, then $[a_n]<[b_n]$ iff $a_n < b_n$ eventually.